# SVG rendering (auto-bluring)

Tags: svg

When i try to render this svg sample, the line is bluring automatically and has 2px height:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500px" height="500px" >                  
    <line x1="100" x2="400" y1="250" y2="250" stroke="black" />
</svg>
```

But when Y coordinates becomes 250.5, all is OK - line has 1px height.

It would be a solution (adding 0.5 pixels), but I need to use scale transform on elemets. On transformed elemets the problem again.

How to solve it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By blurring you mean anti-aliasing. Try the crisp-edges rendering mode, e.g.:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500px" height="500px" >                  
    <line x1="100" x2="400" y1="250" y2="250" stroke="black" shape-rendering="crispEdges" />
</svg>
```

Comment: It is OK for normal browsers, thank you! But in IE9 not woks =(

Comment: This isn't great when zooming out as the lines vanish with shape-rendering="crispEdges"

Comment: +1 upvote - Agreed @magritte - it's going to have to be an engineering trade-off: everything has pros and cons. I'd be interested to know if there was a mode that provided crispEdges while also preserving very fine lines zoomed out as you describe. For a while, I've been interested in an algorithm that could warn of such a scenario - particularly for printing certain complex Chinese and Japanese characters at certain sizes - here a missing stroke would give the character a different meaning or no meaning at all - which is very undesirable of course.